# Keep session on while in virtual terminal

Tags: kubuntu, login, session, kde5, virtual-console

I like to use a virtual console (accessed by CTRL + ALT + F<1;6>) for sys configuration and management on my laptop.
After returning to a KDE session (the one with GUI - no idea how do you call it :) ) session by CTRL + ALT + F7 key in Kubuntu, after few minutes of using it, the login screen appears and requires logging again.

It could be the power management thing, but can I force it to don't require login (or stop it during that time), after I actually used that console?

All advice appreciated :)
Thanks

---

Edit:
Well, I don't want to disable the screensaver. I just look for some workaround to "keep alive" the screen while (typing) in the virtual console. Send some keepalive signal once a while or whatever
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may have enabled the screensaver and the "lock screen" option; you can verify this by waiting for the screensaver timeout while you stay in the KDE screen (instead of switching to a virtual terminal), which should result in the same behaviour. To solve this, either switch of the screensaver altogether, or disable the lock option - which may not be what you want for security reasons.

Comment: I don't want to switch it off completely. Please see edited answer

Comment: In this case you're almost there; you know what you want to do and all you need to do now is search the web for "linux simulate mouse movement" and pick one of the many solutions.